# How strip unused list item tags using PHP

Tags: php

How can I remove list item tags where the fields are empty?

```
<div>
<ul>
<?php

$a = '<li>'.$a.'</li>';
$b = '<li>'.$b.'</li>';
$c = '<li>'.$c.'</li>';
$d = '<li>'.$d.'</li>';

echo $a;
echo $b;
echo $c;
echo $d;
?>

</ul>
</div>
```

This is a simplified version

Comment: what do you mean by fields? you mean variables are empty?

Answer (score 0):

With your example, you should write your php like this:

```
$result = '';
$result .= '<li>'.$a.'</li>';
$result .= '<li>'.$b.'</li>';
$result .= '<li>'.$c.'</li>';
$result .= '<li>'.$d.'</li>';

echo preg_replace('/<li><\/li>/', '', $result);
```

Comment: If `$a = 0`, I'm not sure `<li>0</li>` is considered as empty.

Comment: Yes, you're right. We have several ways to fix the requirement. You should use `'' === $a` to check variables because `'' == 0` will return true. Personally, I like my solution to solve the problem instead of check a lot of variables line by line..

Comment: @ApexCapstone It depends on how you consider a field is empty. Eg: If you want to ignore all white spaces and 0, the replacement should be `preg_replace('/<li>[\s0]*<\/li>/', '', $result);`. If your data has any variable with while space, eg: `' ', '    '`... `empty` function will not solve your problem. It depends on what you need an pick the right way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>

<?php

$a = isset($a)?"<li>$a</li>":"";
$b = isset($b)?"<li>$b</li>":"";
$c = isset($c)?"<li>$c</li>":"";
$d = isset($d)?"<li>$d</li>":"";

// echo $a.$b.$c.$d; You can do this

echo $a;
echo $b;
echo $c;
echo $d;

?>

</ul>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) in a function for this.

```
<div>
<ul>
<?php
$a =  build_line_item($a);
$b =  build_line_item($b);
$c =  build_line_item($c);
$d =  build_line_item($d);
echo $a;
echo $b;
echo $c;
echo $d;
function build_line_item($var) {
    return !empty($var) ? "<li>{$var}</li>" : '';
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

With this approach you'll only need to make a change in one place if your "empty" definition changes. The current empty rules can be found here, http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php.

Comment: @ApexCapstone Yea, that's the same idea, just a bit longer to type out. With this approach if you want `e-g` you'd only need the assignment and the call. You also could shorten the name `build_LI()`.